# r - generating a negative binomial distribution by bootstrapping/resampling

Tags: r

I have a dataset that represents the mall arrivals per week for 158 weeks (3 years).

```
mall_arrivals <- c(15981 ,18291 ,18253 ,17403 ,19201 ,18681 ,20170 ,18735 ,18714, 
18962 ,19430, 18920 ,17529, 19572, 18815, 18918, 17399, 18285, 18685 ,18589, 
17943, 17760,17741,18479 ,17952 ,17789 ,17706 ,17272 ,18235 ,17801, 17858, 17855, 
18820 , 17810 ,18374, 18168, 18006 ,18942, 18357, 17432, 18340, 18610 ,18218 ,18410 ,
18241, 20046 ,18140 ,18796 ,18229 ,20329 ,21572 ,15452 , 3269 ,15141 ,18359 , 17785 ,
18124 ,18724 ,18700, 18584 ,18418 ,18600 ,18464 ,18439 ,18298 ,18642 , 18831 ,18938 ,
17258 ,17416,18282 ,18302 ,18581, 18059 ,17743 ,17836, 17661, 17581, 17574 ,17240 ,17476,
17113 ,17901 ,17361 ,17300, 17554 ,18346, 17960 , 18071, 18358 ,17957, 18089 ,17696,
18002, 18502 ,18558 ,18601 ,18092, 18032, 18598, 19064 ,19167 ,18525 ,22022, 15167 ,
3587, 15267, 17551 , 9764 , 9677, 18660 , 18853 ,18680 , 18545 , 18378 , 19031 , 18784,
20487 , 16963 , 18652, 18331, 18216, 18085 ,18636, 18091 ,17787, 17842, 18022 ,17785 ,
17823, 17989 ,17854, 17488, 17650 ,18247, 17964, 17834 ,17557, 18000, 18616, 18228, 18293 ,
18569, 18224 ,17832, 18631, 18711 ,18677, 18268 ,19077, 19011, 18574, 19533, 19360,
19349 ,22649 ,15127 , 3601)
```

This dataset is a negative binomial distribution according to below:

```
library(fitdistrplus)
fit.negative.binomial.mall.arrivals <- fitdist(mall_arrivals, "nbinom")
fit.negative.binomial.mall.arrivals$estimate
size          mu 
26.08927 17873.30565
```

Now i'm being asked to generate a random distribution based on this distribution using resampling. My R skills and stats are a bit dated, but i tried this

```
resample_mall_arrival <- replicate(100, mean(sample(mall_arrivals, 158, replace = TRUE)))
```

Now I have values with decimal places (continuous) in that resample_mall_arrival which don't make sense. mall arrivals are discrete variables. How do you resample and make sure what you get is still discrete values?

Also, I'm thinking the way to generate this negative binomial distribution is to use rnbinom

```
rnbinom(n, size, prob, mu)
```

But what would be the values that I'll use?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what parameter have you been asked to use to summarise your resamples during resampling?

Comment: I was not actually asked to use a specific parameter.

Comment: Well you're using the mean of your sample to build a random distribution with by resampling. Is that what you were intending to do?

Comment: i was exploring what the replicate function can do and trying to play around with possible parameters. what parameter do you suggest that i use so ill still get discrete values? I tried median, it was all discrete but the range of the values being resampled were quite limited

Comment: Wouldn't it be `rnbinom(100, size=26.08927, mu=17873.30565)`? And just remove the `mean` function from your first approach. I don't think you need any function applied to your sampling.

Comment: Maybe i'm getting all the concepts mixed up or maybe i didn't understand the instructions, rnbinom(100, size=26.08927, mu=17873.30565) will give me a generated distribution that is based on the mall_arrivals' distribution (negative binomial). I think that in itself is the answer to the "generate a random distribution based on this distribution", im just trying to understand where does resampling comes in.